# Difference between "label", "categorize" and "arrange"

Tags: verbs, differences, context

Can the verbs, like label, categorize, and arrange, be used to mean the same, as in:

> - The [states](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states) are **labeled** with their U.S. postal abbreviations, their founding date and capitals.
> - The states are **categorized** with their U.S. postal abbreviations, their founding date and capitals.
> - The states are **arranged** with their U.S. postal abbreviations, their founding date and capitals.

Most likely, the verb list, classify, and sort are also the possible terms here, as in:

> - The states are **listed** . . .
> - The states are **classified** . . .
> - The states are **sorted** . . .

Please, give some guide to me, if I am asking wrong, or if all of these verbs used interchangeably.

Comment: Note that, the verbs you used have their own preposition choice e.g. We say classified **into**, labeled **with**, arranged **in**, listed **with**, and categorized **into**.

Comment: They’re not really interchangeable. Which you pick depends on what you’re doing with them: applying labels, grouping by category, arranging functionally, etc.

Comment: Label = give a name or tag; categorise = put into a category/pigeonhole/group; arrange = to place in a particular order or position in relation to something else.

Comment: No, Iqbal, never. Verbs like label, categorize, and arrange can not be used to mean the same, as in anything… nor could listed, classified or sorted contribute anything but the depth of your own understanding. 

What did your dictionaries, paper or on-line, tell you about the differences among those words, please?